# How to force download the csv file after creation in python

Tags: python-2.7, csv, browser, local, force-download

I am trying to force download a **CSV** file on browser in **python**. CSV file is generating but not **downloading** from on browser.

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution to downlaod the file in browser in Bottle Framework

```
import csv
from bottle import HTTPResponse,response
# Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.

headers = {}
headers[str("content-type")] = 'text/csv'
headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="somefilename.csv"'
f = open(FILE_PATH + 'somefilename.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(['First row', 'Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'])
writer.writerow(['Second row', 'A', 'B', 'C', '"Testing"', "Here's a quote"])
f.close()

file = open(FILE_PATH + 'somefilename.csv', "r")
return HTTPResponse(body=file.read(), status=200, headers=headers)
```

Comment: instead of writing to file, you can just print to output: `csv.writer(sys.stdout)`